# Does cryptography ecdsa support SHA3

Tags: python-cryptography

I am using cryptography to implement some blockchain application, after I looked code, I don't know how to distinguish SHA2-256 and SHA3-256.

Comment: I believe the implementation is only sha2-256. See the [test page](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/development/test-vectors/#hashes)

Answer (score 0):

The [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) supports any hash function not limited to the SHA family, as MD5. SHA-3 should be supported, yes, indeed, I recommend using it as it is a [open contest standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_hash_function_competition)  and improves security.